EVs using fuel cells
I was shocked today to learn that TWO gallons of gasoline (or 3 gallons of liquid propane) contains approximately as much raw energy as the 77 kWh battery in my fancy Tesla Model Y Long Range.   Yet the Tesla can get up to 300 miles out of that energy.
I believe the reason for this is that the EV uses the energy far more efficiently.  (I believe I've heard that the average ICE vehicle is about 20% efficient). I imagine this also explains why the range of an EV is far more sensitive to factors such as headwinds/tailwinds and large elevation changes.  (I drive mine westward to a mountain house, and believe me, it's true).
My question: Why not build an EV that carries its fuel as gasoline or liquid propane, and generates the electricity using a fuel cell ?  I gather efficiencies of 80% or more are possible, so much greater ranges could be achieved.
There are issues of course:

Fuel cells are expensive.   But so are lithium-ion batteries.

Grid electricity is generated more and more cleanly every day.   Not true with electricity from fossil fuels (be it burning them, or in a fuel cell). But using 1/5 as much of them helps a lot.

Fuel cells certainly can't generate the instantaneous power required by an accelerating EV.   So some intermediary power source would be required.   A small battery that the fuel cell keeps charged ?  Maybe even a super-capacitor ?



Turning the hydrocarbon into hydrogen is messy and inefficient. Practical fuel cells are only about 60% efficient. You have to multiply the two efficiencies together. Modern engines are more efficient than 20%, that number has been hanging around since 1973.

I didn't realize the fuel cell would have to turn the hydrocarbon into hydrogen first.

Toyota have produced a fuel cell powered vehicle called the Mirai. It's been in production since 2014.
Not many units have been produced, compared to other brands of cars, and its sale it restricted to fleet cars buyers because it uses hydrogen as a fuel and sources of hydrogen are limited and currently no country has a network of hydrogen refueling stations.
The advantage of hydrogen fuel cell is that water is produced, which drips onto the road.
Toyota has a website for more information.
One advantage a fuel cell vehicle has over a battery powered vehicle is refueling the hydrogen tank takes less time than charging battery, particularly of the initial residual charge level of the battery is low.
In addition to hydrogen powered fuel cell vehicles, Toyota is experimenting with hydrogen powered internal combustion engine vehicles. As with fuel cell vehicles, these are also limited by the limited sources for hydrogen and a lack of a hydrogen fuel network.
